# Brightness indicator in the panel icon missing

Tags: 14.04, brightness

[As you can see the box icon with stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksgV7.png)
After a normal update I met with this. During updates I saw something related to brightness indicator, but I don't know about the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this problem changing the path to icon in file

> /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness

check if this image file exists

> /usr/share/notify-osd/icons/gnome/scalable/status/notification-display-brightness-full.svg

create a backup

> cp /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness /some/backup/folder

find the line you need to change

> ind = appindicator.Indicator ("indicator-brightness",
>                                 "/usr/share/notify-osd/icons/Humanity/scalable/status/notification-display-brightness-full.svg",

then replace it with

> ind = appindicator.Indicator ("indicator-brightness",
>                                 "/usr/share/notify-osd/icons/gnome/scalable/status/notification-display-brightness-full.svg",

That fixed my problem so I hope it will help you.